# Open applications don't appear on panel

Tags: lxpanel

On my other RPi when I open an application a new panel item appears at the top of the screen in the bar.  However on the other one this is not the case so when I minimise an application window, I cannot recover it.  I have obviously done something really stupid so apologise ahead of what will I'm sure be a blindingly obvious fix! :-)

A

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may have accidentally removed the task bar applet from the panel.

Try right clicking on the panel then `Add/Remove Panel Items`. Check that `Task Bar (Window List)` is shown on the list. If not press `Add` to re-add it and `up`/`down` to put it in the right place. Also tick the box in the stretch column so it fills all available space